# Why Log.d() and Log.v() not printing

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I'm using Android 2020.3 version.

It is currently being tested on Android 11 (api 30) version.

When writing in Log.d or Log.v, the log does not work,

and Log.e, Log.w, Log.i, and Log.wtf work normally.

why doesn't it work??

ps. it works normally on Android 10 device.

ps2. Android 11 Device Log output level is **VERBOST**

Thanks you

- Logcat Image
  [Logcat Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1Kl1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try unchecking the `Regex` option. Either way, I have tried logging on API 30 and its working fine for all options.

Comment: I'm selected No Filters, But Same Situation

Comment: Can you please share your code so that I can take a look?

Comment: public class WorkListFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@androidx.annotation.Nullable LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.d("WorkListFragment", "Hello Log d");
        Log.e("WorkListFragment", "Hello Log e");
        Log.w("WorkListFragment", "Hello Log w");
        Log.v("WorkListFragment", "Hello Log v");
        Log.i("WorkListFragment", "Hello Log i");
        Log.wtf("WorkListFragment", "Hello Log wtf");
}

Comment: Doesn't seem like any issue here. Try updating Android Studio to 2020.3.1 or better reinstall it completely. Make sure you take the backup of IDE config first.

Comment: I'm Create New Project and Writing Log, that's printing... Only existing project Log is Not Working

Comment: Check if log statements are executed with the help of debug breakpoints.

Comment: I'm Sorry. This problem only occurred on Samsung devices.

Comment: I solved this problem. Thanks for your help. Good Luck bro